# How to setup a CI env in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm totally new to .net. Actually the main language I work on is Java. So I'm more familiar with CI pipe in Java.

In our java develop environment, we have 
  1. a SVN repository to store code 
  2. a bamboo server to trigger build(code compile and UT, a tool named maven is used here) and also test automation 
  3. a sonar server which will analyze code coverage, code rule, code complexity and etc...

Compare to .net, now we only have
  1. a TFS repository to store code

But how about the other two things? Is there any CI tool for .net to automatically watch code repository to build on demand and also analyze the code quality?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Five seconds of searching on Google led me to search for `windows continuous integration`, which led me to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software).

Comment: I'll let someone else comment on the specific tools you have, but I would be very surprised if you couldn't stipulate a custom command for bamboo, all you then need to do is execute `msbuild.exe [your solution file]`

Comment: bamboo is a commercial and not free. I would like a free tool for CI. Thanks for help.

Comment: TFS ships with a build server, however, many rightly choose to use a different product. TeamCity, CruiseControl.NET and FinalBuilder (not free) are all good choices. TeamCity is the most polished and beginner-friendly of the two free options mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). It can monitor a TFS server and kick off an MSBuild command when it detects new commits to your repository. It can do code coverage via unit test integration as well.